# Patch size in keras.layers.Conv2D?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the one paper I recently read. 
On this paper network looks like this.

[image]

As in the picture, the first layer has 11x11 patch size. But I don't see any patch size parameter in keras.layers.Conv2d documentation.

How to add these layers in keras.Sequential() ?

Comment: Looks like `patch size = kernel_size` :)

Answer (score 2):

The patch size is also referred as kernel size:

```
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

You can use the `kernel_size` parameter.